# Question on generating functions about lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

[image: Solution]

[[image: Question][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8WG7.png)

This is a screen shot of a problem and solution from Stanley vol 2 but I tried working it out and I can not figure it out. The only thing that I could relate is that $$G(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x-x^2}}$$. Would anyone be kind to explain the solution to me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more information about which part of the solution you don't understand, or exactly where you start getting lost?

Comment: @angryavian I don’t know how the first and second generating functions were derived. If the first can be explained, I should be able to get the second one.

Comment: @angryavian Sorry to bother you with part of the question that I already asked but I can't seem to draw a S-path from $(0,0$ to $(3,3)$ that dont just contain the single step $(3,3)$ and that it stay strictly below the line $y=x$ except at the origin and at the point $(3,3)$. Is this not the path from $(0,0) \rightarrow (2,1) \rightarrow (3,3)$ ? But this S-path does not contain the single step $(3,3)$. I would really appreciate it if you could help clarify this, as it would help clear things out the S-paths of the set $P_m$ looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n$ is the generating function for some class $\mathcal{A}$ of objects, then $\frac{1}{1-A(x)} = 1 + A(x) + (A(x))^2 + \cdots$ is the generating function of the collection of all sequences of objects from $\mathcal{A}$.

$K(x) + P(x)$ is the generating function of steps of types (i) and (ii), while $K(x) + 2P(x)$ is the generating function of steps of all three types.

Since $H(x)$ is the generating function of sequences of steps of types (i) and (ii), it is $H(x) = \frac{1}{1-(K(x) + P(x))}$.
Similarly, $G(x) = \frac{1}{1 - (K(x) + 2P(x))}$.